# What is this LEGO minifigure with yellow face shield and lots of teeth?

Tags: minifigures, minifigure-identification

I found this LEGO Minifigure and I can't identify him or what set it came from.

[image: minifigure with yellow face shield and lots of teeth]

Comment: Howdy Shawn, welcome to Bricks.SE.  Thanks for the clear picture.  If you feel like Mathew has answered your question it is good to click the checkbox next to his answer.

Answer (score 17):

This look to be [Rebel Pilot U-wing](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sw0800#T=S). (Note that in your image the torso is back-to-front)

[image: Rebel Pilot U-wing]

He comes in just one set: [U-Wing Microfighter](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75160-1#T=S).

[image: U-Wing Microfighter]

Comment: I just have to wonder... so does this guy have faces printed on two sides of his head? Or does he come with a spare head?

Comment: He’s got faces printed on both sides. Lego has been making faces like this for a while to have multiple expressions